# Setting random values to half of the dictionary and copying the rest

Tags: python, dictionary, random, key

I have a python dictionary created by an other list via:

```
a = dict.fromkeys(some_list)
```

Because I created this dictionary via the above command all my values in the dictionary are `None` as expected. And it looks like this:

```
a = {('A', 'B'): None,
     ('A', 'C'): None,
     ('B', 'A'): None,
     ('C', 'A'): None}
```

What I want is: to be able to change the `None` values to random numbers via `random.uniform(0,1)`.

However I don't wanna do this to whole of the dictionary instead only the first 2 keys (`('A', 'B')`, `('A', 'C')`), and the rest (`('B', 'A')`, `('C', 'A')`) should be copied from the first 2 keys.

Following sets all the values to random numbers. However I could not find a way to set the first two as random and the rest copied without hardcoding the keys.

```
for key in a:
    a[key] = random.uniform(0, 1)
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: What I meant is `AB.value == BA.value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
visited = set()

for key in a:

  if key in visited:
    continue
  
  # mark key as visited
  visited.add(key)
  visited.add(key[::-1])

  value = np.random.uniform(0, 1)

  a[key] = value
  a[key[::-1]] = value
```

---

More dynamic and efficient solution is to **hash** the given key such that the tuple-order is being ignored

```
def hash_tuple(t):

  hash_value = 0

  for elem in t:
    
    if isinstance(elem, int):
      
      hash_value += elem
    
    elif isinstance(elem, str):

      hash_value += ord(elem)
    
    else:

      raise ValueError(f'Invalid Type {type(elem)}')
  
  return hash_value
```

---

```
global_seed = np.random.randint(0, 100)

for key in a:

  seed = hash_tuple(key) + global_seed
  random = np.random.RandomState(seed)

  value = random.uniform(0, 1)

  a[key] = value
```

Comment: I think this will also work, but I was really looking for most simplistic option. But thank you though!!

Comment: I think this is a better solution than the accepted answer. With the accepted answer, I think you would update the value associated with the ('A', 'B') key twice: once when the iterator reaches ('A', 'B'), and once when the iterator reaches ('B', 'A').

Comment: You are right @AlexWaygood however this won't work, if the key has 3 elements like ('A', 'B', 1) and the other key is ('B', 'A', 1). any suggestion instead of `key[::-1]`?

Comment: I found it  change the `key[::-1]` to `key[:2:][::-1] + (key[2],)` for 3 element tuples

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the keys in your `dict` weren't inserted in any particular order:

```
for key in a:
    n = random.uniform(0, 1)
    a[key] = n
    if (key[1], key[0]) in a:
        a[key[1], key[0]] = n
```

Comment: I think this works. Basically the only thing I wanted to achieve is putting the random numbers to my keys, and equalizing the duplicated/transposed versions with that random number.

Comment: Then yes, this accomplishes exactly that :)

Answer (score 0):

My method allows not only two elements in the key tuple, can be any number and the order also doesn't matter.

```
import random

a = {('A', 'B'): None,
     ('A', 'C'): None,
     ('B', 'A'): None,
     ('C', 'A'): None}

tuple_group_dict = {t: ''.join(sorted(t)) for t in a.keys()}
# print(tuple_group_dict)
group_rand_dict = {g: random.uniform(0, 1) for g in tuple_group_dict.values()}
# print(group_rand_dict)
for k in a:
    a[k] = group_rand_dict[tuple_group_dict[k]]
print(a)

# {('A', 'B'): 0.19127468345979626, ('A', 'C'): 0.5162477118368421, ('B', 'A'): 0.19127468345979626, ('C', 'A'): 0.5162477118368421}
```